# When resizing Vim, automatically gq the whole file?

Tags: vim

How do I make vim gq my entire file if I resize the window? I have wrapmargins, not textwidth set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `` :autocmd VimResized * normal! "maHmbgggqG`bzt`a" `` (last part based on "Restoring the view" section of [the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.10)).  I have not tested this, though.  It overwrites two of your marks, so you might want to change the letters after `m` and `` ` `` from `a` and `b` to something else.  You might need to set `textwidth`, either to the value of `&columns` during the autocmd or to `0`.